# python subprocess.Popen kill process with child processes

Tags: python, subprocess, kill-process

How do I send a Ctrl-C to process or kill process with child processes?

Example of my code (python 2.7):

```
# --*-- coding: utf-8 --*--
import subprocess
import os
import signal

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping localhost'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.pid

a = raw_input()
os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

I see next processes when I run program:

```
user   16078  0.0  0.0   4476   916 pts/6    S+   14:41   0:00 /bin/sh -c ping localhost
user   16079  0.0  0.0   8628  1908 pts/6    S+   14:41   0:00 ping localhost
```

Program output:

```
16078
```

After raw_input:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subproc2.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

I want kill process pid 16078 and pid 16079.

How would I do this and what the bug in program? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would I do this and what the bug in program?

If you want to kill all processes which includes in process group then you should use parent process id. Like that:

```
os.killpg(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

If you want to kill only one child process then use this:

```
os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: Thank you! The error went missing, and main process "/bin/sh -c ping localhost" was killed. But "ping localhost" process remained. Is it possible kill both processes?

Comment: Your script  with my correction will spawn only one "ping" process and at the end of the program it will be killed. Kill all ping processes and check again.

Comment: Thank you! code "os.killpg(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)" work for me!

Comment: Then choose my answer as solution and up vote it. Also you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group

Comment: This kills the actual Python process with all subprocesses, and not the subprocess with subprocesses.